# Ionic 2 - Runtime Error No provider for NavController

Tags: ionic2

I understand there are similar questions based on this. I believe my scenario is little different. I am trying to check a value in native storage, if it is true. I am trying to navigate to the HomePage. By now after reading couple of articles,I know i wont be able to use the NavController a dependency injector.

I have also tried using @ViewChild , but for that I assume I would need to define a variable in the template that I will use. However I am using an html template. I am new to Ionic 2 and Angular 2, so please go little easy on me :-).

Any other way in which i can accomplish that? Please elaborate a bit more if you guys have a solution to this.

This is my code from app.components.ts (below). Currently I have just commented the navCtrl code.

```
import { Component,ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
import { LoginPage } from '../pages/login/login';
import { NativeStorage } from '@ionic-native/native-storage';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'app.html',

})
export class ClassetteApp {
  @ViewChild("appNav") nav: NavController;
  rootPage:any = LoginPage;

  constructor(platform: Platform, statusBar: StatusBar, splashScreen: SplashScreen, private nativeStorage : NativeStorage) {
    platform.ready().then(() => platform.ready().then(() => {
       this.nativeStorage.getItem("userId").then(function(data){
        this.nav.push(HomePage);
        },function(error){
         this.nav.push(LoginPage);
        })
      statusBar.styleDefault();
      splashScreen.hide();
    })
    )}
}
```

here is my app.html.

```
<ion-nav #appNav [root]="rootPage"></ion-nav>
```

Comment: check [here](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavController/) _You can't inject NavController because any components that are navigation controllers are children of the root component so they aren't available to be injected._

Comment: @sebaferreras, thanks for pointing out the app.html, I completely missed that. Now I have implemented `@ViewChild`, I get another error  **Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'nav' of undefined**

I get that error only when i add this line of code `this.nav.push(LoginPage);` to the error function, am I missing something or not using it properly. I would need to redirect to another page when there is an error. Please advise

Comment: Try by changing `navApp` to `appNav` here -> `@ViewChild("appNav") nav: NavController;`

Comment: Thanks a ton!.. how stupid of me to even ignore that!!

Comment: Been there, done that lol Please accept suraj's answer so we can close this question :)

Comment: when i comment out this line `//this.nav.push(LoginPage); ` it works fine?. Am I doing another stupid mistake agian?. I would want to navigate, but when I remove the comment, i get the same error.

Comment: @Arun- check updated answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check [here](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavController/). *You can't inject NavController because any components that are navigation controllers are children of the root component so they aren't available to be injected.*

You have the wrong id.

```
@ViewChild('appNav') nav: NavController
```

It should be the same as the `#appNav` id you have given in the html.

Lastly you are using a regular function as a callback. The `this` points to function object instead of the class. So it cannot find `nav`. Use [Arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

```
this.nativeStorage.getItem("userId").then((data)=>{
        this.nav.push(HomePage);
        },(error)=>{
         this.nav.push(LoginPage);
        })
```

Comment: I am guessing it's not the ID that's giving me the problem. I corrected that. It is still giving me the same error for this line of code `//this.nav.push(LoginPage);` [from the code sample posted at the top].  When i comment it out, it works fine. Still clueless about it.. :-(. is it a scope issue? . Any advice ?

Comment: Oh right!. Thanks for pointing it out!.. that worked like a charm!!

Answer (score 0):

An update to that answer, I found out we can use this below: Make sure you have the latest Ionic version. 3.3.0. Here you don't have to add a variable to your html template.

```
import { NavController, Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import { LoginPage } from '../pages/login/login';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'app.html'
})
export class MyApp {
  @ViewChild('appNav') nav: NavController;
  loginPage: any = LoginPage;

   /* your code */

   SomeFunction(){
   this.nav.push(loginPage);
  }   
}
```