# Getting the error "No provider for NavController" when trying to pass data from child component to parent component

Tags: html, angular, typescript, ionic2

I'm trying to send data from my home.ts file to the app.component.ts file using EventEmitter and Output. But everytime I reference the home page component in my app.html I get this seemingly random error. When I remove NavController from the constructor in home.ts, the error goes away.

home.ts :

```
     import { Component, EventEmitter, Output } from '@angular/core';
     import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

     @Component({
     selector: 'page-home',
     templateUrl: 'home.html',
     })

     export class HomePage {
     message : any;
     @Output() notify : EventEmitter<Object> = new EventEmitter<Object>();

    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {

    }
    ionViewDidLoad(){
    this.message = {"Name":"Sid", "Age":17};
    this.notify.emit(this.message);
   }
 }
```

app.html :

```
  <ion-nav [root]="rootPage"></ion-nav>
  <page-home (notify)="getChildData($event)"></page-home>
```

app.component.ts :

```
  import { Component, ViewChild, ViewChildren } from '@angular/core';
  import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
  import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
  import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';

 import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';
 @Component({
  templateUrl: 'app.html'
 })
 export class MyApp {
 rootPage:any = HomePage;

 constructor(platform: Platform, statusBar: StatusBar, splashScreen: 
 SplashScreen) {
  platform.ready().then(() => {
  // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
  // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
  statusBar.styleDefault();
  splashScreen.hide();

  });

 }
 getChildData(message){
   console.log(message["Name"]);
   console.log(message["Age"]);

 }
}
```

How do I fix this error ? I need to use the NavController so I can't remove it. I want to still be able to send data from the child component to the parent component

Comment: Refer https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/why-cant-i-import-navcontroller-and-viewcontroller-into-service-or-app/40999/46

Answer (score 0):

The error is pointing out that you should provide the NavController in the providers section somewhere. This section could be in several modules of your application but the general one is the app.module.ts file.

In there you have a providers section in which you can provide services or providers for the Angular dependency injection mechanism to work appropriately.

So my first thougth would be to add the navController in the providers section of your app.module.ts file. This ensures that Angular can resolve the dependency to your NavController. Putting it in the app.module.ts file makes it having the same instance fo your navcontroller all over your application.

```
@NgModule({
    bootstrap: [ AppComponent ],
    declarations: [
        ...
    ],
    imports: [ 
        ...
    ],
    exports: [
    ],
    providers: [ 
    ...
        NavController
    ]
})
```

However, since you are using ionic, I would check out a related topic on the following url.

[Ionic 2 - Runtime Error No provider for NavController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44198058/ionic-2-runtime-error-no-provider-for-navcontroller?rq=1)

Comment: I did try adding NavController to the providers array in app.module.ts, but that just spouted more errors, and based on what I've seen from tutorials and general practice, you shouldn't add it there anyway. The problem is that I can't use NavController in home.ts, not app.component.ts. I want to understand why sending data from the child component to the parent component causes this error. If I don't send any data, this error does NOT occur. And like I said before, if I do not inject NavController in the home.ts constructor, the error also does not occur then.